# Is there a way to run perl code during cpan install after tests have passed?

Tags: perl, cpan

I have my own cpan mirror which has some injected modules for our internal use only. I would like to run some perl code during cpan install. Currently I'm injecting the code directly to Makefile.PL, but the problem is that that it is run before "make test". I would like the code being run only after the distributions tests have passed.

One option would be to inject the code in the end of the last test file, but how do I know if all tests in all testfiles have passed? Test::More->builder->is_passing seems to know only about the current test file.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine why you could possibly want such a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option (if you are using `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`) is to [define a `MY::test` function](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#Overriding-MakeMaker-Methods) in `Makefile.PL` to (conditionally) add an extra task. Something like

```
 # Makefile.PL
 ...
 sub MY::test {
    my $text = shift->SUPER::test(@_);  # original 'test' action for this system
    if ($ENV{BOOM}) {
        $text =~ s/^(test ::.*)$/$1 GO-BOOM/m;
        $text .= q~
GO-BOOM ::
    $(PERL) -E 'say "BOOM!"'
~;
    # note: important to use tab, not spaces, before "$(PERL) ..."
    }
    return $text;
 }
```

In the `Makefile`, the `test` action will now either look like

```
test :: $(TEST_TYPE) subdirs-test GO-BOOM
...
GO-BOOM ::
        $(PERL) -E 'say "BOOM!"'
```

or

```
test :: $(TEST_TYPE) subdirs-test
```

depending on what happened in `Makefile.PL`. (These are typical linux specs in the Makefile. Your results may vary).

If you have defined the `BOOM` environment variable when you ran `Makefile.PL`, and if the prior actions related to `make test` are successful, then the `test` action will also perform the `GO-BOOM` action. But if a test fails, then `GO-BOOM` will not run.

```
$ BOOM=1 perl Makefile.PL
$ make test TEST_FILES=t/test-that-will-pass.t
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/test-that-will-pass.t
t/test-that-will-pass .. ok    
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=16,  4 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr  0.01 sys +  0.06 cusr  0.01 csys =  0.09 CPU)
Result: PASS
"/usr/bin/perl" -E 'say "BOOM!"'
BOOM!

$ make test TEST_FILES=t/test-that-will-fail.t
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/test-that-will-fail.t
t/test-that-will-fail.t .. 1/? 
#   Failed test at t/test-that-will-fail.t line 2.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
t/test-that-will-fail.t .. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/test-that-will-fail.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr  0.01 sys +  0.03 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.05 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/1 test programs. 1/1 subtests failed.
Makefile:938: recipe for target 'test_dynamic' failed
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 1
```

(no boom)

Comment: Does this only work with MakeMaker, or also with other Makefile.PL modules?

Comment: Thanks! With your example I got it doing exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This is a MakeMaker solution.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would use a meta-distribution.  Say, Task::MyCorp.  This would then prereq all of the modules you want, and have the added benefit of having a test phase that won't run until all the prereqs have successfully tested.

In fact, I often do have such a meta module, much like [common::sense](https://metacpan.org/pod/common::sense) where I can automatically load strict, warnings at the level I want, and import any other functions I want available everywhere (logging and translation being the two big ones).  It would be a convenient place to prereq everything in many cases.

Obviously, without knowing how you have everything set up, I can't be sure this will work for you. There is no one-size-fits-all solution, so if this isn't sufficient, perhaps it will kick off some ideas that *will* work in your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it does not work for my use case. I would like to run the code for several of my modules which I mostly don't want to have all installed.